# NodeJS writes to MongoDB only once

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS app that is supposed to generate a lot of data sets in a synchronous manner (multiple nested for-loops). Those data sets are supposed to be saved to my MongoDB database to look them up more effectively later on.

I use the mongodb - driver for NodeJS and have a daemon running. The connection to the DB is working fine and according to the daemon window the first group of datasets is being successfully stored. Every ~400-600ms there is another group to store but after the first dataset there is no output in the MongoDB console anymore (not even an error), and as the file sizes doesn't increase i assume those write operations don't work (i cant wait for it to finish as it'd take multiple days to fully run).

If i restart the NodeJS script it wont even save the first key anymore, possibly because of duplicates? If i delete the db folder content the first one will be saved again.

This is the essential part of my script and i wasn't able to find anything that i did wrong. I assume the problem is more in the inner logic (weird duplicate checks/not running concurrent etc).

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, dbBuffer = [];
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/loremipsum', function(err, db) {
    if(err) return console.log("Cant connect to MongoDB");
    var collection = db.collection('ipsum');
    console.log("Connected to DB");

    for(var q=startI;q<endI;q++) {
        for(var w=0;w<words.length;w++) {
            dbBuffer.push({a:a, b:b});
        }
        if(dbBuffer.length) {
            console.log("saving "+dbBuffer.length+" items");
            collection.insert(dbBuffer, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Error on db write", err);
                    db.close();
                    process.exit();
                }
            });
        }
        dbBuffer = [];
    }
    db.close();
});
```

**Update**

- db.close is never called and the connection doesn't drop
- Changing to bulk insert doesn't change anything
- The callback for the insert is never called - this could be the problem! The MongoDB console does tell me that the insert process was successful but it looks like the communication between driver and MongoDB isn't working properly for insertion.

Comment: `collection.insert` is an async call, so your final `db.close()` call happens before those complete.

Comment: Also, this is a good use case for [Bulk.insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) (instead of the dbBuffer array hack)

Comment: @JohnnyHK As mentioned, this is a simplified example of multiple nested loops that actually run multiple days. I can see in the MongoDB console that the connection isnt closed as well. Felipe: Youre right and i will try it out, but it shouldnt really be a big difference.

Comment: Changed the code now and ran it on a different machine, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it myself. One misconception that i had was that every insert transaction is confirmed in the MongoDB console while it actually only confirms the first one or if there is some time between the commands. To check if the insert process really works one needs to run the script for some time and wait for MongoDB to dump it in the local file (approx. 30-60s).

In addition, the insert processes were too quick after each other and MongoDB appears to not handle this correctly under Win10 x64. I changed from the Array-Buffer to the internal buffer (see comments) and only continued with the process after the previous data was inserted.

This is the simplified resulting code

```
db.collection('seedlist', function(err, collection) {
    syncLoop(0,0, collection);
    //...
});

function syncLoop(q, w, collection) {
    batch = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp({useLegacyOps: true});
    for(var e=0;e<words.length;e++) {
        batch.insert({a:a, b:b});
    }
    batch.execute(function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        //...
        return setTimeout(function() {
            syncLoop(qNew,wNew,collection);
        }, 0); // Timer to prevent Memory leak
    });
}
```